# Difference across columns in a data.table

Tags: r

Sorry if it might be a quite basic point, but I fail to find a convenient tool.

I have a (quite large) data table and want to difference across columns, that is

```
A     B     C     D

9     N.A.  3     2
15    4     N.A.  N.A.
N.A.  N.A   2     3
```

I want to create a new column E that is the what is left of A after differencing B, C, and D. For N.A.s in columns B,C and D, I can assume zeros, but when there is a N.A. in A I have to ignore this observation. So the final result should be

```
A     B     C     D     E

9     N.A.  3     2     4
15    4     N.A.  N.A.  11
```

I was removing all the columns in DT that are N.A. in A by
DT <- DT[!(DT$A=="N.A.")]

and then I tried 
DT[, E:= lapply(.SD, diff), .SDcols = c("A", "B", "C", "D")]. 
but that fails because of the N.A.'s. 
I don't want to manually change the N.A.s into 0 (because later on I might want to distinguish what was a real zero and what was what I imputed)- I'd like to do it inside a function. Does anybody have a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume all columns ar with type character.

```
require(data.table)

DT <- data.table(A = c("9", "15", "N.A."),
                 B = c("N.A.", "4", "N.A."),
                 C = c("3", "N.A.", "2"),
                 D = c("2", "N.A.", "3"))
DT <- DT[A != "N.A."]
```

Compute row number.

```
DT[, rownum := .I]
```

You will get warnings because `N.A.` can not be converted to type numeric.

```
DT[, E := as.numeric(A) - sum(as.numeric(B),
                              as.numeric(C),
                              as.numeric(D), na.rm = T), by = rownum]
DT
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
df$E[!is.na(df$A)] = 2*df$A[!is.na(df$A)] - rowSums(df[!is.na(df$A),], na.rm = T)
```

Example:

```
df = data.frame(A = c(19,25,NA,17),B = c(1,2,3,4), C = c(5,NA,NA,9), D = c(3,1,2,NA))

>df
   A B  C  D
1 19 1  5  3
2 25 2 NA  1
3 NA 3 NA  2
4 17 4  9 NA

df$E[!is.na(df$A)] = 2*df$A[!is.na(df$A)] - rowSums(df[!is.na(df$A),], na.rm = T)

> df
   A B  C  D  E
1 19 1  5  3 10
2 25 2 NA  1 22
3 NA 3 NA  2 NA
4 17 4  9 NA  4
```